# VBA using arrays that are the return value of a fuction

Tags: arrays, vba, return-value

So I have this function called "mergeSort" which I use as a helped function, I would like to use the array that it returns, but I can not find how you would do this. I have tried this:

```
Dim result(9) As Integer
result = mergeSort(numbers(), 9)
```

It is giving me a compile error:

> *Can't assign to an array.*

Any advice to letting use the mergeSort's return data would be most appreciated. Here is the signature for the `mergeSort` function:

```
Function mergeSort(numbers() As Integer, sz As Integer) As Integer()
```

Comment: But, what is written inside your function "mergeSort" ? can we see all your codes and that error message (inner)? also you can check this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49417/Sorting-Algorithms-in-VB-NET-How-To-Implement-Merg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign one array to another (i.e. the result from `mergeSort` to `result`), make sure the array on the left-hand side of the assignment is resizable and the types of the array match.

```
Dim result As Variant 
result = mergeSort(numbers(), 9)
```

For more information see [MSDN Can't assign to an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264711(v=office.15).aspx)